# Create a hotkey that allows an event to be toggled on and off after a button is pressed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pynput

Trying to make a hotkey (`Shift + d` for example) that toggles an event on or off.

There are two entry boxes. The top one has the word or phrase you want to be said. The bottom one is the cooldown period between each time the word/phrase is said. Right now it is set up so that when the "enter" button is clicked it just starts typing out the phrase immediately with the cooldown.

I would like it so when the "enter" button is clicked, it won't start typing out till you toggle it with a hotkey( like `shift + d`), and then stops once you press it again. I've tried messing around with `pynput` but everything I do either causes errors or when I click the button the program just crashes.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Checkbutton, Entry, Frame
import time 
import threading
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode, Controller, Key
from pynput import keyboard

#Main window of the Gui
root = Tk()
root.title("Phrase Test")
root.configure(bg="black")
root.geometry("250x100")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#delete text in entry box
def some_callback(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")
    return None

#Command Entry box
e = Entry(root, width=25, bg="#101010", highlightbackground="black", fg="white", justify="center")
e.pack()
e.insert(0, "Enter your phrase:")
e.bind("<Double-1>", some_callback)

#Cooldown entrybox
e2 = Entry(root, width=25, bg="#101010", highlightbackground="black", fg="white", justify="center")
e2.pack()
e2.insert(0, "Enter cooldown time:")
e2.bind("<Double-1>", some_callback)


#Command
def makemoney():

    keyboard = Controller()
       
    while True:
        keyboard.type(e.get())
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(e2.get())

#Activate Button
myButton = Button(root, text="Enter", command=makemoney, bg="black", highlightbackground="black", fg="white")
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your question, you could try something like this (it's one out of multiple ways in which you can do this)

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Checkbutton, Entry, Frame
import keyboard

#Main window of the Gui
root = Tk()
root.title("Phrase Test")
root.configure(bg="black")
root.geometry("250x100")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#delete text in entry box
def some_callback(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")
    return None

def check():
    global pressed
    if keyboard.is_pressed('Shift') and keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
        keyboard.press('\b')
        if not pressed:
            pressed=True
            makemoney()
        else:
            pressed=False
            root.update()
    root.after(100,check)

def makemoney():
    if pressed:
        keyboard.write(e.get())
        root.after(int(e2.get())*1000,makemoney)

#Command Entry box
e = Entry(root, width=25, bg="#101010", highlightbackground="black", fg="white", justify="center")
e.pack()
e.insert(0, "Enter your phrase:")
e.bind("<Double-1>", some_callback)

#Cooldown entrybox
e2 = Entry(root, width=25, bg="#101010", highlightbackground="black", fg="white", justify="center")
e2.pack()
e2.insert(0, "Enter cooldown time:")
e2.bind("<Double-1>", some_callback)

pressed=False

#Activate Button
myButton = Button(root, text="Enter", command=check, bg="black", highlightbackground="black", fg="white")
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

- I have used the `keyboard` module instead of `pynput`, it should be sufficient for your use case.
- I have tried not to use the infinite `while` loop with `time.sleep()` function as it interferes with the main thread, instead I have used  the `.after()` method to schedule the calling.
- I have defined a function `check()` which checks the key press event of `Shift + d`, changes the `pressed` flag and calls the `makemoney()` function accordingly. It repeats itself after every `100` milliseconds.
- The `makemoney()` function calls itself after every specified seconds if the hotkey has been pressed for the first time.

You can improve the code but I hope this has provided an idea on how to go about.